# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed (code 19)

Tags: android, sqlite, constraints

I've this code for creating my sqlLite DB in android application:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABELLA_PERSONE = "CREATE TABLE TB_PERSONE "
+ "(_ID integer,"
+ "CODICE_PERSONA text not null, DESC_PERSONA text null, "
+ "PRIMARY KEY (CODICE_PERSONA));";
```

and

```
private static final String CREATE_TABELLA_USCITE = "CREATE TABLE AN_USCITE "
+ "(_ID integer, "
+ "CODICE_USCITA text null, SCADENZA text null, DATA text null,"
+ "PERSONA text not null REFERENCES TB_PERSONE(CODICE_PERSONA) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE      CASCADE,PRIMARY KEY(CODICE_USCITA));";
```

When i call the function for DELETE a row in "TB_PERSONE"

```
public int SQLdelete(String tabella, String id) {
    return database.delete(tabella, "_ID=" + id, null);
}
```

the application show me this error:

```
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException:           
foreign key constraint failed (code 19)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:727)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1494)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at it.jackpot21.personalmoney.DbAdapter.SQLdelete(DbAdapter.java:89)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at it.jackpot21.personalmoney.PersoneActivity$5.onClick(PersoneActivity.java:215)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-27 11:15:27.152: E/AndroidRuntime(22031):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone help me pls? 
Thanks a lot! :)

EDIT: 
I solved it by putting `ON DELETE SET NULL`.
Thanks at all!

Comment: what you have tried? check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117685/android-database-sqlite-sqliteconstraintexception-error-code-19-constraint-fai

Comment: and also check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929277/error-inserting-android-database-sqlite-sqliteconstraintexception-error-code-19

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are deleting a record from `TB_PERSONE`, which is referenced by record(s) from table `AN_USCITE`.

So,

1) either delete the records from `AN_USCITE` prior to deleting record from `TB_PERSONE`.

or

2) set `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your foreign key definition:

```
...
PERSONA text not null REFERENCES TB_PERSONE(CODICE_PERSONA) ON DELETE CASCADE ...
...
```

Comment: but I must not delete the record in `AN_USCITE` if I delete one in `TB_PERSONE`.

Comment: if you still need the AN_USCITE you may need some mapping table

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `AN_USCITE` table still contains some record that references the person you're trying to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that `String id` not null so your code below can be executed.

```
public int SQLdelete(String tabella, String id) {
    return database.delete(tabella, "_ID=" + id, null);
}
```